# How would you say "this song is played" and "in some places/cities" in natural Japanese?

Tags: translation

I'm having trouble saying the following thing in Japanese: "This song is played when the traffic light turns green in some places in Japan."

Specifically, I don't what would be 'the most natural/correct way' to say "this song is played" and "in some places".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You probably need to reword this question including what your attempts were, and any related knowledge you have about it.  Otherwise it risks being closed as asking for a translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This song is played when the traffic light turns green in some places in Japan."
日本の一部の地域では、信号が青になったときにこの曲が流れます。

"this song is played"  is  "この曲が流れる"
"in some places"  is  "一部の地域で" or "いくつかの場所で"

Hope this helps!